Fetch unique row with unique combination from a csv file using linux / mac terminal
I have a csv file using tens of thousands of records . The file is so huge cannt be exported to excel properly . The file has 3 values SOURCE,PROT,SPORT . All with different combinations and repetitions . I want to have a unique list that contains all unique data considering above filed . What would be the command to read the csv and get the unique value as given below?

Output:


https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9918/printing-unique-lines
